# Why does my code produce "UNIQUE constraint failed: parent_reply.parent_id" error while the one I'm following doesn't?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I'm currently following a [sentdex's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9os9uQJqDbI&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDdc2k5dwtDTyT9aCja0on8j&index=5) to creating a deep learning chatbot with Python and TensorFlow. It uses a dataset of one month's worth of reddit comments and an sqlite3 database.

My issue is that whenever I try to run my code I get:
`UNIQUE constraint failed: parent_reply.parent_id`

While I understand what would produce the error, I can't find the reason why the original code from the tutorial works seamlessly and mine doesn't (I've already went through both mine and his code from top to bottom and couldn't find any significant differences).

I've already tried changing the sql queries in `insert_parent_exists` and `insert_no_parent` methods from `INSERT INTO parent_reply` to `INSERT OR REPLACE` and `INSERT OR IGNORE` but both of them produce a database with `False` as the parent's value where applicable. I've also noticed that commenting out one of those methods in the last `else` block of my code makes the code run without any error, but not producing any paired comments (as far as I understand, if only one of those functions runs, the `PRIMARY KEY` is not being violated, thus no error).

Below I've provided both mine and sentdex's code (main script loop and methods used for database insertions).

**My code:**

```py
import json
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime

path = '/Users/MateuszGrzybek/Desktop/DL-Chatbot/data/RC_2015-01'
db_transaction = []


def db_connect(conn, cursor):
    """Create all the necessary tables."""
    try:
        cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS parent_reply;')
        # create table
        print('Creating tables...')
        cursor.execute(
            """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parent_reply (parent_id TEXT PRIMARY
            KEY, comment_id TEXT UNIQUE, parent TEXT, comment TEXT,
            subreddit TEXT, unix INT, score INT);""")
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            print('Table created.')


def replace_comment(parent_id, comment_id, parent_data, body,
                    subreddit, created_utc, score):
    """Replace a comment if it doesn't fit."""
    try:
        query = """UPDATE parent_reply SET parent_id = '{}', comment_id = '{}',
        parent = '{}', comment = '{}', subreddit = '{}', unix = {},
        score = {} WHERE parent_id = '{}';""".format(parent_id, comment_id,
                                                     parent_data, body,
                                                     subreddit,
                                                     int(created_utc), score,
                                                     parent_id)
        transaction_builder(query)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))


def insert_parent_exists(parent_id, comment_id, parent_data, body, subreddit,
                         created_utc, score):
    try:
        query = """INSERT INTO parent_reply (parent_id, comment_id, 
        parent, comment, subreddit, unix, score) VALUES ('{}', '{}',
        '{}', '{}', '{}', {}, {});""".format(parent_id, comment_id,
                                             parent_data, body, subreddit,
                                             int(created_utc), score)
        transaction_builder(query)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))


def insert_no_parent(parent_id, comment_id, body, subreddit,
                     created_utc, score):
    try:
        query = """INSERT INTO parent_reply (parent_id, comment_id,
        comment, subreddit, unix, score) VALUES ('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}',
        {}, {});""".format(parent_id, comment_id, body, subreddit, int(created_utc),
                           score)
        transaction_builder(query)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))


def transaction_builder(query):
    """Build a database transaction"""
    global db_transaction
    db_transaction.append(query)
    if len(db_transaction) > 1000:
        cursor.execute('BEGIN TRANSACTION;')
        for query in db_transaction:
            try:
                cursor.execute(query)
            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e))
        conn.commit()
        db_transaction = []


if __name__ == "__main__":
    conn = sqlite3.connect('2015-01-1.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    db_connect(conn, cursor)
    row_count = 0
    paired_rows = 0

    with open(path, buffering=1000) as f:
        for row in f:
            row_count += 1
            row = json.loads(row)
            body = format_body(row['body'])
            parent_id = row['parent_id']
            score = row['score']
            subreddit = row['subreddit']
            comment_id = row['name']
            created_utc = row['created_utc']
            parent_data = find_parent(parent_id)

            if score >= 2:
                existing_comment_score = find_existing_score(parent_id)
                if existing_comment_score:
                    if score > existing_comment_score:
                        if acceptable_comment(body):
                            replace_comment(parent_id, comment_id,
                                            parent_data, body, subreddit,
                                            created_utc, score)
                else:
                    if acceptable_comment(body):
                        if parent_data:
                            insert_parent_exists(parent_id, comment_id,
                                                 parent_data, body,
                                                 subreddit, created_utc, score)
                            paired_rows += 1
                        else:
                            insert_no_parent(parent_id, comment_id, body,
                                             subreddit, created_utc, score)

            if row_count % 100000 == 0:
                print('Total rows analyzed: {}\nPaired Rows: {}\nTime: {}'.
                      format(row_count, paired_rows, str(datetime.now())))
```

**Tutorial code:**

```py
import sqlite3
import json
from datetime import datetime

timeframe = '2015-01'
sql_transaction = []
path = '/Users/MateuszGrzybek/Desktop/DL-Chatbot/data/RC_2015-01'
connection = sqlite3.connect('sent(1).db')
c = connection.cursor()


def create_table():
    c.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS parent_reply;')
    c.execute(
        """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parent_reply(parent_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
        comment_id TEXT UNIQUE, parent TEXT, comment TEXT, subreddit TEXT,
        unix INT, score INT)""")


def transaction_bldr(sql):
    global sql_transaction
    sql_transaction.append(sql)
    if len(sql_transaction) > 1000:
        c.execute('BEGIN TRANSACTION')
        for s in sql_transaction:
            try:
                c.execute(s)
            except:
                pass
        connection.commit()
        sql_transaction = []


def sql_insert_replace_comment(commentid, parentid, parent, comment, subreddit,
                               time, score):
    try:
        sql = """UPDATE parent_reply SET parent_id = ?, comment_id = ?,
        parent = ?, comment = ?, subreddit = ?, unix = ?, score = ?
        WHERE parent_id = ?;""".format(parentid, commentid, parent, comment,
                                       subreddit, int(time), score, parentid)
        transaction_bldr(sql)
    except Exception as e:
        print('s0 insertion', str(e))


def sql_insert_has_parent(commentid, parentid, parent, comment, subreddit,
                          time, score):
    try:
        sql = """INSERT INTO parent_reply (parent_id, comment_id, parent,
        comment, subreddit, unix, score) VALUES ("{}", "{}", "{}", "{}", "{}",
        {}, {});""".format(parentid, commentid, parent, comment, subreddit,
                           int(time), score)
        transaction_bldr(sql)
    except Exception as e:
        print('s0 insertion', str(e))


def sql_insert_no_parent(commentid, parentid, comment, subreddit, time, score):
    try:
        sql = """INSERT INTO parent_reply (parent_id, comment_id, comment,
        subreddit, unix, score) VALUES ("{}", "{}", "{}", "{}", {}, {});""".format(parentid, commentid, comment, subreddit, int(time), score)
        transaction_bldr(sql)
    except Exception as e:
        print('s0 insertion', str(e))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_table()
    row_counter = 0
    paired_rows = 0

    with open(path, buffering=1000) as f:
        for row in f:
            row_counter += 1
            row = json.loads(row)
            parent_id = row['parent_id']
            body = format_data(row['body'])
            created_utc = row['created_utc']
            score = row['score']
            comment_id = row['name']
            subreddit = row['subreddit']
            parent_data = find_parent(parent_id)
            if score >= 2:
                existing_comment_score = find_existing_score(parent_id)
                if existing_comment_score:
                    if score > existing_comment_score:
                        if acceptable(body):
                            sql_insert_replace_comment(comment_id, parent_id,
                                                       parent_data, body,
                                                       subreddit, created_utc,
                                                       score)

                else:
                    if acceptable(body):
                        if parent_data:
                            sql_insert_has_parent(comment_id, parent_id,
                                                  parent_data, body, subreddit,
                                                  created_utc, score)
                            paired_rows += 1
                        else:
                            sql_insert_no_parent(comment_id, parent_id, body,
                                                 subreddit, created_utc, score)

            if row_counter % 100000 == 0:
                print('Total Rows Read: {}, Paired Rows: {}, Time: {}'.format(
                    row_counter, paired_rows, str(datetime.now())))
```

I excpect the output to be the effect of the last print statement:

```
Total Rows Read: 100000
Paired Rows: 3718
Time: 2019-05-02 14:43:52.472389
```

and not the error that my code for some reason produces.

Comment: *"While I understand what would produce the error, I can't find the reason why the original code from the tutorial works seamlessly and mine doesn't (I've already went through both mine and his code from top to bottom and couldn't find any significant differences)."* You mentioned code differences but what about table differences (data)?

Comment: Your `parent_reply` table probably shouldn't be using `parent_id` as the primary key, as multiple replies can be made to a single comment....

Comment: @RaymondNijland The original code produces the table with the same structutre as my code does with `INSERT OR REPLACE/IGNORE`

Comment: @Shawn Removing the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint from `parent_id` still produces the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through trial and error I've found that in his code he does:

```py
def transaction_bldr(sql):
    for s in sql_transaction:
        try:
            c.execute(s)
        except:
            pass
```

while I was doing:

```py
def transaction_builder(query):
    for query in db_transaction:
        try:
            cursor.execute(query)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
```

He simply passed on any exception that could occur during the sql transaction, thus no error while running his code. Changing the `except` block to `pass` brought up another error in my code: `Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 8, and there are 0 supplied` at `replace_comment` method. I got it fixed by changing the replacement fields from `{}` to `?`. I could use some elaboration as why would that matter though.